# Profile image does not upload

Tags: images, uploads, media, permissions

when i logged in "Font-End" as a user "Employer" and try to upload my profile image, it does uploaded but when i click update i got this alert error " No editor could be selected.
Successful update " and nth happen for the profile picture it remains blank and and when i check Dashboard > Media i don't find the image there neither

PS: other images in other pages do work just fine when i upload them, seems the problem just with users profile pictures and covers

i will really appreciate your help guys

[image]

Comment: Can you possibly include the code snippet in your question? Otherwise I think it is very difficult to answer your question. Also, are you using the default profile image feature of wordpress, or that of a plugin?

Comment: What code snippet i shall include in my question please ?  and i using the default profile image feature of wordpress

Comment: Okay, thanks? Try to use the "Inspect" function (right click > Inspect) of your browser. Then go to "Inspect" and click on the empty image. If there is a blank div or a img with a blank src attribute, then it is most likely a theme error.

Comment: i just backed up the website and run it locally (localhost) and it worked fin

Comment: Ok, nice that your error is fixed then. Have a nice day!

Comment: On the browser it says "src=(unknown)"                       <div class="alert alert-dismissible user-img"> 
         <div class="page-wrap" id="cs_employer_img_box">
                     <figure>
                           <img src="" id="cs_employer_img_img" width="100" alt="">
                           </figure>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

Comment: Ok, then it's almost certainly the theme - but didn't you say earlier that the bug is fixed? Which theme are you using?

Comment: im using a theme called JobCareer

Comment: Hey, and thanks for your reply. Since the theme is apparently a purchasable premium theme, I can't install it myself. Which hosting provider do you use?

Comment: Hey Chris i really appreciate your replies, i have contacted the host provider cause i believe the problem may be the GD Library needs to be installed

Comment: Okay, thanks for letting me know. Have a good day!